# Helm release to be in custom namespace and not in default

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there a way I can specify the helm release to be deployed on a custom namespace.
All the helm resources are deployed on a custom namespace that I created by mentioning

```
namespace: {{ template "plugin.namespace" . }}
```

and this is taken from _helper.tpl

But the release by itself is in default namespace

```
helm ls
NAME                        NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                           APP VERSION
object-storage-plugin   default     3           2021-08-04 15:42:30.833512 +0530 IST    deployed    object-storage-plugin-2.1.2 2.1.2
```

I know via command line we can set the namespace but I am looking for options from a template file where the namespace would be picked

I referred https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/

With helm3 `--create-namespace` creates new namespace but helm uninstall command doesnt delete this newly created NS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In normal use you *must* use the `helm install --namespace` option to specify the namespace where Helm keeps its persistent data.  There's no way to specify this in a file.

Also in normal use, you wouldn't manually specify the `namespace:` in individual YAML files.  Resources will automatically be installed in the `helm install --namespace` (in the same way as if you `kubectl apply --namespace ... -f ...`).  You should only need `namespace:` for unusual setups where the same chart needs to install things in multiple namespaces; IME that's usually only if you're using Helm for doing cluster-level setup.

However, you also tagged this question as [helmfile](/questions/tagged/helmfile).  If you're using [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile), then in the `helmfile.yaml` file, you can specify the namespace to use there.  The `helmfile.yaml` effectively has `helm install` options listed out in YAML, so you again wouldn't need to specify `namespace:` in templates.

```yaml
# helmfile.yaml
# (not a plain Helm artifact)
releases:
  - name: object-storage-plugin
    namespace: object-storage-plugin       # <-- configure this
    chart: ./charts/object-storage-plugin
    values:
      - values.dev.yaml
  # `helmfile apply` will do the equivalent to
  #
  # helm install object-storage-plugin \
  #   ./charts/object-storage-plugin \
  #   -n object-storage-plugin \
  #   -f values.dev.yaml
```